# Selecting one uploaded avatar (as a moderator) selects the other/both

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, profile-picture, profile-edit

I was editing a user's avatar, and clicked 'Uploaded picture' (the yellow triforce). The preview instead changed to a pink unikitten. Clicking the Change picture button again shows the following:

[image: Yes, it's a unikitten]

Chrome/Mac

Comment: So you are really going to change @Unionhawk avatar?

Comment: Reproducing on IE11/Windows. You truly are the worst by the way.

Comment: Possible line of enquiry: one picture was uploaded by @Unionhawk, the other by me.

Comment: That's just Uni's force fields at work. Unifields, we call them.

Comment: @TimPost There is a term for bugs caused by me and/or my account? I feel so loved

Comment: @Unionhawk Unibugs.

Comment: *Achievement unlocked: lucky 7* ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Tim posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258228/140505), the only person that should be able to upload an avatar image to their profile is the user themselves.

Moderators (and employees) have the ability to revert an uploaded avatar to an identicon - there is no need for them to upload different avatars.

I've implemented checks for this which will be with you in the next build.

Comment: Does the same go for other profile fields? It is possible for a moderator to change a user's display name, should they only be able to reset/wipe that too?

Comment: @fredley reset, most likely, can't see any reason to let moderators choose whatever they want. Too tempting. (of course will be glad to stand corrected :))

Comment: I for one have had my name changed by a moderator (before I was a moderator).

Comment: @fredley That's a valid moderator use case, if the display name itself is offensive, mods should be able to change it to the generic "user12345" instead (or back to what it was previously if someone's account was clearly compromised)

Comment: @TimPost Yeah, hence the 'reset' to user12345 instead of changing. Does the other situation ever happen?

Comment: @fredley It has, when folks walk away from their computer and forget to lock it (coworkers, you can't trust any of 'em) - but a reset button is sufficient for that case as well. Will (probably) do that.

Comment: @TimPost Really, reset needs to be the only action, and only possible for publicly viewable free-text fields.

Answer (score 9):

As a moderator, there's no use case for uploading a custom avatar for a user. There's really not even a support case for employees to do it. The only time mods should be changing a user's avatar is if it's found to be reasonably objectionable, in which case you should just change it to the default identicon and notify the user they're free to upload another (less objectionable) avatar.

While we could conceivably fix this, I don't think it's warranted, as this really shouldn't happen to begin with :)

I'm not saying I'm anti-unihorned-unicat, but this isn't a case we really should support. I'll defer to a core dev to put a status on this, but it's not something I'd like for mods to be able to do.

Comment: Was it definitely the uploading of avatars by two users that's the problem? Can a normal user not have two uploaded pictures for their account?

Comment: @fredley A normal user can, it's the fact that you uploaded it (AFAICT)

Comment: Oh well then. :(

Comment: Why give the ability to do something that you can't actually do, then? Show the moderator only the relevant stuff, i.e. only the "identicon" part and this way people won't get confused. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's _probably_ just an oversight.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We *do* need the ability to change avatars, if someone uploads something offensive.

Comment: @fredley not change, reset. As Tim said, even SE staff can't upload whatever they want and put as user's avatar. (unless a developer actually changes the raw database, and this happened only once as far as I can tell, as April 1 prank)

Comment: For the record, I use my gravatar by default. @fredley just hates change, and as such, wants to go back to an avatar I had used from the beginning of my chat account to around 2014.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh yeah. The problem here is that *shouldn't* is not backed up by *can't*.

Comment: @Uni no worry, he does not have such power. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, not anymore, because he broke it already.

Comment: Would you believe that [I play video games with these fools](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19198427#19198427)?

Comment: @TimPost At least he's not MarcIRL with the power to change my Minecraft username too >_>

Comment: @Unionhawk I'm going to contact Mojang