# Why isn't there a horizontal scrollbar in the "about me" section?

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, horizontal-scroll-bar

I cannot see a horizontal scrollbar in the "about me" section where there are long images

Where did the horizontal scrollbar go? Shouldn't it be there?

Comment: Err its not [unibugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258227/selecting-one-uploaded-avatar-as-a-moderator-selects-the-other-both#comment841739_258227) right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically because:

```
.user-card .about {
    height: 278px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; //<-- see "hidden"?
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    max-width: 63%
}
```

Can we make it appear? Sure. We change "hidden" to "auto" (or just replacing `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` with `overflow:auto`):

> [image]

We see the bad width (it's actually height for a horizontal scroll bar), so we do:

```
.about::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    height:6px; //<-- adding this!
    background: #f4f4f4
}
```

And everything is sorted:

> [image]

I don't know the purpose of disallowing the horizontal scrolling, probably devs will fix that.

Comment: Actually, no. It was the 6 flag

Comment: @Uni So you should edit it, don't be a liar :P

Comment: Too bad I might say no. But fix might roll out in ~3 years time